# Unable To Build Lupa

Tags: python, lupa

I'm trying to compile Lupa on Windows 7 64bit, and I've installed all of the dependencies (including LuaJIT2 and Lua 5.2). But when I try to install by running

> python setup.py install

I get errors regarding dependancies, usually .m files.

For example:

> lupa/_lupa.c(265) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file:
>   'lua.h': No such file or directory

I've tried adding the files manually but it just leads to more issues, like this:

```
c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:118:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define INT_LEAST64_MIN INT64_MIN
 ^
In file included from _lupa.c:271:0:
stdint.h:154:0: warning: "INT_LEAST64_MAX" redefined [enabled by default]
  #define INT_LEAST64_MAX 0x7fffffffffffffff
 ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\stdint.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\include\wchar.h:876,
                 from unicodeobject.h:120,
                 from Python.h:85,
                 from _lupa.c:30:
c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:123:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define INT_LEAST64_MAX INT64_MAX
 ^
In file included from _lupa.c:271:0:
stdint.h:155:0: warning: "UINT_LEAST64_MAX" redefined [enabled by default]
  #define UINT_LEAST64_MAX 0xffffffffffffffffU
 ^
```

Please note this is a small excerpt from the spam I was getting in the console. I've tried more things than I can keep track of. I've tried using gcc to no avail and had friends try and help me. I'm completely stumped. Please help me!

Oh, and here's a full log of me trying to run the installer without changing files around:

```
No local build of LuaJIT2 found in lupa directory
Checking for installed luajit library using pkg-config
pkg-config found luajit version 2.0.3

building without Cython
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing lupa.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to lupa.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to lupa.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing lupa.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to lupa.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to lupa.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'lupa.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'lupa.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying lupa\version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\lupa
running build_ext
building 'lupa._lupa' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nolog
o /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DLUA_COMPAT_ALL -I/usr/local/include/luajit-2.0 -IC
:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tclupa/_lupa.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\
Release\lupa/_lupa.obj
_lupa.c
lupa/_lupa.c(265) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lua.h': No such file or directory
error: command '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64
\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: is `lua.h` in your path?

Comment: Yeah, but when I type `lua.h` into the console, it's unrecognized.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need the answer for this but I had the same problem and looked into lupa folder and saw `lupa.pyx` which implies you need Cython. Run `pip install cython` beforehand worked for me.

Comment: It sure has been a while, and I sort of gave up on the project, but I'll go back and try that, thanks